# How to read continiusly a value change in Firebase (Android)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use `Firebase` for multiplayer. Everything works great except that I need when one player closes app (`onStop()`, `onDestroy()` etc) the game ends. I have the following `firebase` structure:

```
"PVP" : {
    "active" : {
      "1536394217496" : {
        "didGameEnd" : true,
        "gameMaster" : {
          "didPlayerAnswer" : false,
          "name" : "stelios",
          "playerAnswerCorrect" : false,
          "score" : 2
        },
        "gameSlave" : {
          "didPlayerAnswer" : false,
          "name" : "anna",
          "playerAnswerCorrect" : false,
          "score" : 4
        },
```

I have in `onDestroy`, `onDestroy` etc method to change the "didGameEnd" working fine. My problem is I need to catch the change to run the endgame code. I tried a lot but i cant manage it. Here is my code for this:

```
mGameFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReferenceFromUrl(Constants.FIREBASE_BASE_URL + Constants.FIREBASE_PVP + Constants.FIREBASE_GAME_ACTIVE_PATH + mGameWaitModel.getId());
public void ifGameEnds() {
        mGameFirebase.child("didGameEnd").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Boolean isEnded = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                    if (isEnded == true) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PvPWinningActivity.class);
                        Bundle dataSend = new Bundle();
                        dataSend.putString("Winning Text", winning_text);
                        dataSend.putInt("Your Score", your_Score);
                        dataSend.putInt("Opponent Score", opponent_score);
                        intent.putExtras(dataSend);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

As i can understand the `valueListener` catches the `datachange` so i dont need to do something special here. I guess the problem is with the `boolean` value. I tried it as string with no luck.

Set value works fine so i guess i m pointing in the right place

```
mGameFirebase.child("didGameEnd").setValue(true);
```

Appriciate any help for what is wrong as i m new at Firebase!

After many tries the following code

```
mGameFirebase.orderByChild("didGameEnd").equalTo(true).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

   // this will be triggered only when the value is true, so you can add the thing that you want to make happen, here only

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

works BUT it triggers even of the value is FALSE. So actually its just read the value, not doing what i need.

The following code

```
     mGameEnd =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReferenceFromUrl(Constants.FIREBASE_BASE_URL + Constants.FIREBASE_TEST_PATH + Constants.FIREBASE_GAME_ACTIVE_PATH + mGameWaitModel.getId());
                mGameEnd.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            boolean isEnded = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
if(isEnded) {
        //Your logic
    }


                    }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

throws Nullpoint exception all the time.

Comment: Just for reference the number under "active" is a random Game Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the value for your `didGameEnd` property from `false` to `true`, you need to use the following lines of code in your `onStop()` method:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference didGameEndRef = rootRef
    .child("PVP")
    .child("active")
    .child(uid)
    .child("didGameEnd");
didGameEndRef.setValue(true);
```

To constantly check if this value is changed, you should add the listener on the same reference like this:

```
didGameEndRef.addValueEventListener(/* ... */);
```

And inside the `onDataChange()` method, get the value using these lines of code:

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
    boolean isEnded = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
    if(isEnded) {
        //Your logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your `mGameFirebase` looks something like this:

`DatabaseReference mGameFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("PVP");`

If it does, you can use `childEventListener` to listen to the changes in `didGameEnd` child of your database. The code does not have many changes just, simple additions :

```java
mGameFirebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Boolean isEnded = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.child("didGameEnd").getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

If your `mGameFirebase` points to the reference of the `active` or children below the main node, you can try this, which will only be triggered when the game ends and the value changes:

```java
mGameFirebase.orderByChild("didGameEnd").equalTo(true).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

   // this will be triggered only when the value is true, so you can add the thing that you want to make happen, here only

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: It points to active.Even my previus code was reading the true value i thing. The real problem is where to put the method to read all the time and execute the endGame code. I m trying your code now in onStart() to figure out what is wrong. Thanks a lot for the help! At least i ll have one problem less to check.

Comment: Just for future reference the code you suggest has a warning for recurse infinitely. I dont know if its normal as my problem didnt solved yet and i didnt figure out if its the eventListener or something else.

Comment: It's weird, can you tell what exactly you wrote in the code, because I have used this code, a lot of times and this should not be happening.

Comment: Exactly your code and only my intent for what to do after this. I used the second code of you as my mGameFirebase points to active.

Comment: Can you provide the code to me, so I can look what's the problem.

Comment: I have exactly your code (copy paste) and i double checked that mGameFirebase points to active. After all i have it in the onCreate() it reads the change BUT it reads it fault at the first time. Meaning i have the toast message at the beginning (value become true) and then i have the real change reading. It trigers even if the value is false!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference the following code works:

```
// initialize the game state listener
        mGameEnd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReferenceFromUrl(Constants.FIREBASE_BASE_URL + Constants.FIREBASE_TEST_PATH + Constants.FIREBASE_GAME_ACTIVE_PATH + mGameWaitModel.getId());
        mGameEnd.child("didGameEnd").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    boolean isEnded = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    if(isEnded){
                        if (isGameMaster()) {
                            your_Score = 0;
                            opponent_score = mGameModel.getGameSlave().getScore();
                            winning_text = "You Lost!";
                        }

                        if (!isGameMaster()) {
                            your_Score = 0;
                            opponent_score = mGameModel.getGameMaster().getScore();
                            winning_text = "You lost";
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PvPWinningActivity.class);
                        Bundle dataSend = new Bundle();
                        dataSend.putString("Winning Text", winning_text);
                        dataSend.putInt("Your Score", your_Score);
                        dataSend.putInt("Opponent Score", opponent_score);
                        intent.putExtras(dataSend);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Keep Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

Thanks a lot for the efford!